# ASP NET MVC Area routing/multiple routes issue in VB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, routes, areas, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I'm pretty inexperienced with .net and have just started learning MVC.  I've hit an issue concerning multiple controllers being found:

*"Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'reviews'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter."*

I've recently added a new "Admin" area to my app and within that I have a "ReviewController".  There is also a "ReviewController" within the main app folder:

ah - as a new user I can't post an image, but basically I have a "ReviewController" in "Controllers" and in "Areas/Admin/Contollers".

I have 2 routes set up so far:

**Default route in Global.asax.vb**

```
  Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

     ' MapRoute takes the following parameters, in order: 
     ' (1) Route name
     ' (2) URL with parameters
     ' (3) Parameter defaults

     routes.MapRoute( _
       "Default", _
       "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
       New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}, _
       {"PowellCasting/Controllers"}
     )

  End Sub

  Sub Application_Start()

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()

    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(New System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges(Of Models.PowellCastingEntites))
    Database.SetInitializer(Of PowellCastingEntites)(New PowellCastingInitializer())

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)

    ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("PowellCasting/Controllers")

  End Sub
```

**Area route in AdminAreaRegistration**

```
Namespace PowellCasting.Areas.Admin
  Public Class AdminAreaRegistration
    Inherits AreaRegistration

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property AreaName() As String
      Get
        Return "Admin"
      End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Sub RegisterArea(ByVal context As System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistrationContext)
      context.MapRoute( _
        "Admin_default", _
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
         New With {.Controller = "Dashboard", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
       )
    End Sub
  End Class
End Namespace
```

After reading around the issues I was having, I have added a number of bits of code:

My Admin controllers have the right namespace defined

- Namespace PowellCasting.Areas.Admin rather than simply PowellCasting.
- I have RegisterAllAreas set in the global
- ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("PowellCasting/Controllers") is in place to specify the default route.

The specific problem I have now is that when I go to "/Reviews" I get the multiple controllers error shown above, specifically:

*The request for 'reviews' has found the following matching controllers:
PowellCasting.PowellCasting.Areas.Admin.ReviewsController

PowellCasting.PowellCasting.ReviewsController*

I've enabled the route debugger and that only shows one match:

ah - as a new user I can't post an image but it shows:

Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id} as FALSE

and

{controller}/{action}/{id} as TRUE

This is as expected so I don't know why I'm receiving the issue.

I have read about overloading the maproute method with the namespace, but couldn't find an example in VB (loads in c#).  But I tried this:

```
Public Overrides Sub RegisterArea(ByVal context As System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistrationContext)
  context.MapRoute( _
      "Admin_default", _
     "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
      New With {.Controller = "Dashboard", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}, _
      vbNull,
      {"PowellCasting/Areas/Admin/Controllers"}
  )
End Sub
```

and

```
Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

' MapRoute takes the following parameters, in order: 
' (1) Route name
' (2) URL with parameters
' (3) Parameter defaults

routes.MapRoute( _
    "Default", _
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
    New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}, _
    vbNull,
    {"PowellCasting/Controllers"}
)

End Sub
```

but without success.

I'm sure this should be straightforward and I've tried a number of things - it very frustrating.  Any help would be really appreciated.

My first post on here - Hi! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read carefully the error message you are getting:

> The request for 'reviews' has found the following matching
>   controllers: PowellCasting.PowellCasting.Areas.Admin.ReviewsController
>   PowellCasting.PowellCasting.ReviewsController

you will notice that `PowellCasting` is repeated twice.

So in your main Global.asax route registration:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
    "Default", _
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
    New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}, _
    vbNull,
    {"PowellCasting.Controllers"}
)
```

this assumes that your `ReviewController` in the root is defined like this:

```
Namespace Controllers
    Public Class ReviewController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        Function Index() As ActionResult
            Return View()
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Notice the absence of the `PowellCasting` prefix in the namespace definition (that's a VB subtility which adds it automatically, I suppose that's the name of your application)

and inside the `AdminAreaRegistration.vb`:

```
context.MapRoute( _
    "Admin_default", _
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
    New With {.action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}, _
    vbNull, _
    {"PowellCasting.Areas.Admin.Controllers"}
)
```

which assumes that your `ReviewController` in this area is defined like so

```
Namespace Areas.Admin.Controllers
    Public Class ReviewController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        Function Index() As ActionResult
            Return View()
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Once again notice the absence of the `PowellCasting` prefix in the namespace definition.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - this worked!! :)  I'm still trying to get my head around it all, but it's starting to make sense.  I tried going to "/admin" and that failed but it was also down to my namespace containing "PowellCasting".  Once I took that out it worked as well.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar problem.

I had an application where i had two areas : Common , Products

And when i opened the application , the Common_default route was being called, but when i saw the RoutesCollection.Routes, it showed me 4 routes. Actually i defined only 2 routes - one for common , one for Products.

After reading the above comments, i just gave it a try my changing the project properties for my website.

I changed the default namespace from "MyWebsite.Web" to "MyWebsite" . And it did the trick. My applciation was up and running.

The bottomline is never have "." in the default namespace for your MVC4 website project.

Answer (score 0):

DealerNetworksAreaRegistration.cs :
    //Add Area

```
context.MapRoute(
                "DealerNetworks_default",
                "DealerNetworks/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Dealer", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

---

RouteConfig.cs

```
//Add Namespace

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                //passing the namespace of the HomeController in the Main area using namespace parameter.
                namespaces: new[] { "SMART.Controllers" }
            );
```

---

Global.asax.cs

```
//Register Areas

AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
```